# Find $p \in \Bbb R$ for which $2$ vectors are collinear

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For which $p \in \Bbb R$ are vectors $\vec{a}=(p-1)\vec{i}+2\vec{j}$ and $\vec{b}=(p+4)\vec{i}+(p-2)\vec{j}$ collinear?

Well I know that $2$ vectors are $\textbf{non collinear}$ if and only if $\alpha\vec{a}+\beta\vec{b}=0 \iff \alpha=\beta=0$

So that would mean that if we wanted the linear representation of $2$ $\textbf{collinear}$ vectors to equal zero vector, either $\alpha \neq0$ or $\beta \neq 0$ or both of them are not zero.

$\alpha\vec{a}+\beta\vec{b}=0$

$1$) $\alpha\neq0$, $\beta =0$

$\Rightarrow \alpha\vec{a}+0\vec{b}=0$

This means $\vec{b}$ can be anything, and $\vec{a}=0$, am I right?

$\Rightarrow$ $(p-1)\vec{i}+2\vec{j}=0$

This has no solution?

$2$ ) $\alpha=0$, $\beta \neq0$

$\Rightarrow 0\vec{a}+\beta\vec{b}=0$

For this I also got no solution. And now I'm not sure what to do when $\alpha \neq0$, and $\beta \neq0$?

Comment: For the case where both are nonzero, use the fact that $\exists \alpha,\beta\neq 0, \alpha u + \beta v = 0$ if and only if $\exists \gamma\neq 0, u= \gamma v$ (easy proof). Then solve your equation in $(p,\gamma)$.

Comment: Another method for the whole thing : use the determinant.

Comment: @justt I'm not following you, can you please elaborate? Also, we haven't done matrices nor determinants

Comment: If $\alpha$ is nonzero, you can divide by $\alpha$ and get $\alpha a + \beta b = 0 \iff a + \frac \beta \alpha b = 0 \iff a = - \frac \beta \alpha b$. You can rename $- \frac \beta \alpha = \gamma$. Thus $a = \gamma b$.

Comment: Okay, got it. What I did above was all correct?

Comment: Sorry i missed your answer. What you did above was all correct, yes.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your time!